# Which Harry Potter sets are these?

Tags: set-identification, harry-potter

A very generous person gifted many 20-year-old Harry Potter sets to my son. All but this set of pieces had instructions and boxes. I’m not sure what is left. For minifigs there’s Harry, Dumbledore, Draco, a suit of armor, and a Phoenix. Any ideas as to what these are?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

On the left of the image, you have [4730-1 The Chamber of Secrets](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4730-1), and on the right of the image you have [4709-1 Hogwarts Castle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4709-1)

The Chamber of Secrets came with Minifigs of Harry Potter, Ron Weasley, Gilderoy Lockhart, Ginny Weasley, and Tom Riddle, as well as a Basilisk (giant snake) and Fawkes (Phoenix)

Hogwarts Castle came with Albus Dumbledore, Draco Malfoy, Harry Potter, Hermione Granger, Ron Weasley, Severus Snape, Rubeus Hagrid, Peeves, and a Knight.

While available as separate sets, they also came together in [a "kit"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=K4701-1) with the addition of [4705-1 Snape's Classroom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4705-1)

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help. It looks like we’re likely missing some pieces, but no matter. We’re still happy to have them.